# How to Fix Negative-Like Output for Single Image Plot? (plt.imshow(X[0].permute(1, 2, 0)))

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am trying to visualize Cifat10 images on my local machine. I have established a conda environment with `python=3.11` and installed `numpy, matplotlib, pytorch`, and `scikit-image`. I installed pytorch via `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

The code snippetbelow is what I am currently using. When I execute it on both my local machine and Google Colab, the results are consistent. However, when I try to plot a single image, the displayed image appears inverted, despite not having any transformations other than resize and center crop. The bigger issue is that this is not limited to just the plot. Interestingly, when I save the images, the negative effect is also in the saved files.    What is the issue? and how I can fix it?

**The code**

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torchvision.datasets as datasets

transform = T.Compose([
    T.Resize(256),
    T.CenterCrop(224),
    T.ToTensor(),
    # T.Normalize(
    #     mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
    #     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])


train_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(
    root='./data',
    download=True,
    transform=transform
)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size= 16, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

X,y = next(iter(train_loader))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 8, figsize=(12, 4))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    image = X[i].permute(1, 2, 0)
    # image = torch.clamp(image, 0, 1)  # Clamp pixel values within [0, 1]
    ax.imshow(image)
    ax.axis('off')


plt.show()
```

**output when running on the Google Colab**
[image]

**output when running on my local machine**
[image]

These are consistent. However, when I try the following what I get form google colab correctly showing while on my machine it is like a negative/inverted image! The belly of the frog should be white, but on my machine it shows black. They are as follows:

```
plt.imshow(X[0].permute(1, 2, 0))
```

**output when running on the Google Colab**
[image]

**output when running on my local machine**

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same output as the one, which got in Colab. Probably the issue is with the night mode or something in the browser or the editor that your are using.

Comment: Hi @Venkatachalam it is not about dark mode or browser because even saving images are balck

Comment: okay, but your problem is not reproducible at my end.